# Purpose of init pattern in obj-c and its use

Tags: ios, objective-c-2.0, objective-c-runtime

What is the purpose of the  initializer pattern other then in order to assure that the object is properly initialized by its superclass before the init method performs its initialisation.

Why is this necessary?

and

when we have a class which has more than one initialization method, why others shoud call the dedicated initialiser instead of superclass initialiser?

I'm coming from java background so don't fully understand this - the closest i could match in java was singleton pattern but the part others calling dedicated initialiser didn't make sense to me as in java you have a choice rather then you "should".

can any one elaborate....thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The initializer pattern is necessary, because the `super` class whose initializer you are calling, can return any kind of object, not necessarily the instance of that class. That's how, for example, `NSString` works, it's actually a cluster of classes implementing different kinds of strings optimized for different usage patterns. So calling `self = [super init]` for `NSString` descendant makes self, for example, an `NSCFString` instance.
2. There's a pattern called *Designated Initializer* in Objective C. If the class has many initializer, one of them is chosen as designated, and all the other should be implemented by calling it, not the super. This is important for correctly overriding initializers in child classes, you should initialize only the designated one, and it will be called under all circumstances (assuming your code is well-written and takes advantage of designated initializers, of course :)

Comment: thx for that info, i guess this throws 3 curiosity to me

1) means there is no such thing as static final for methods in obj c correct?

2) and all Nxxx methods can be overridden in all child classes implementing your own features?

3) does obj c allows multiple inheritence like C++? or its more like single inheritance.

Comment: @RedMan 1. if `static final` means not overridable, then objective-c lacks it (that's a concept of Objective C, to allow to override every method, even of third-party classes) 2. Yes, all methods can be overriden in child classes (if it's legal to override that class) and in categories (category is just a "patch", a set of additional and reimplemented class methods) 3. There's no multiple inheritance, but there are protocols (java interfaces?) and message forwarding, which can be of help.

Comment: thx for the info in java / obj c terms what is protocols is it same as java interface as you stated? and message forwarding? i thought apple dev doc refer all this as object message passing if its bit of same thing?
one thing bafels me a lot is synthesis is there any close comparison to this in java?

Comment: 1. Protocols declare set of methods the class implementing this protocol should (or may for optional methods) implement. 2. Message forwarding is a way for class to react to messages it doesn't implement, for example to redirect them to a child object. 3. Messages in objc is just a name for function calls. 4. `@synthesize` just generates accessor methods for your properties. 5. Please consider +1 my answer :)